# pandas fillna takes too long

Tags: python, pandas

```
def load_data():
    data = pd.read_csv('data-WDI/WDI_Data.csv')
    print('filling na..')
    data.fillna(data.groupby(['Country Name', 'Indicator Name']).transform('mean'), inplace=True)
    data.set_index(['Country Name', 'Indicator Name'], inplace=True)
    data = data.to_panel()
    # save only data for the years, the rest is redundant
    years = [str(year) for year in range(1960, 2016)]
    data = data[years]
    return prepare_test_and_train(data)
```

The program gets to the imputing of missing values and hangs. If I don't impute them, it runs relatively fast. Why does it hang? Should the groupby take that long?

Comment: You could set the index before doing the groupby/fillna. Try profiling to find what line/call is expensive.

Comment: I know that the groupby is expensive, when I don't fill missing values, it runs in seconds and not minutes. If I set the index before that, I get a "KeyError: 'Country Name'", and I don't know how else to group by.

Comment: Ok, I moved the groupby before that (with groupby(level=[0,1])), and the script is stull way too slow.

Comment: If you fill a `string` to a `float` data column, that will take very long.